# Make all Divs in html table cell have the same height as the highest div in CSS

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML Code:

HTML:

```
<table>

    <tbody>

        <tr>

            <td>
                <div class="item">
                    Item 1
                </div>

                <div class="item">
                    Item 2 <br>
                    More Text <br>
                    Even More Text <br>
                </div>

                <div class="item">
                    Item 3
                </div>

                <div class="item">
                    Item 4
                </div>


                <div class="item">
                    Item 5 <br>
                    More Text <br>
                    Even More Text <br>
                    So Much Text <br>
                    Ok Enough Text <br>
                </div>

                <div class="item">
                    Item 6
                </div>
            </td>

        </tr>

    </tbody>

</table>
```

CSS:

```
table tr tbody td {
    width: 800px;
}

.item {
    display:inline-block;
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 200px;
}
```

The width of each cell is 800px

Each Item in the Cell is going to be 200px

So the Cell will have 3 items then it will wrap and have another 3 items

Is it possible to make the height of all the div items equal to the highest one using only CSS? Currently the height of each is determined by the text inside it.

Comment: after adding height:100% to html and body elements if you give height 100% to .item... they will all be as tall as the TD which is stretched to this height because of the tallest div.

Comment: @NawedKhan I don't want them to be as tall as the <td> I want all of them to be as tall as the div with the most text, is that possible in CSS? I'm trying to avoid using javascript/jquery

Answer (score 1):

Using flexbox this is quite simple, although this may cause some unintended downsides:

```css
table tr tbody td {
    width: 800px;
}

td {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 800px;
}

.item {
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 5px;
    min-width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<table>

    <tbody>

        <tr>

            <td>
                <div class="item">
                    Item 1
                </div>

                <div class="item">
                    Item 2 <br>
                    More Text <br>
                    Even More Text <br>
                </div>

                <div class="item">
                    Item 3
                </div>

                <div class="item">
                    Item 4
                </div>


                <div class="item">
                    Item 5 <br>
                    More Text <br>
                    Even More Text <br>
                    So Much Text <br>
                    Ok Enough Text <br>
                </div>

                <div class="item">
                    Item 6
                </div>
            </td>

        </tr>

    </tbody>

</table>
```

Comment: Items 3, 4, and 5 should wrap since the width of 3 div items plus the padding is close to the width of the <td>, is tehre a reason why they don't wrap with flex?

Comment: I've adjusted the answer to include wrapping.